# How can I verify that an RTMP stream URL is working?

Tags: cdn, flash, video-streaming, rtmp

I have been put in charge of setting up a CDN account for streaming video but am not actually running the site that will host the content. How can I test that a published RTMP URL is working? Do I need to create a test page with a Flash video player or is there a simple tool that can consume RTMP streams that can be used to test? The URL is in the following format:

`rtmp://example.fcod.llnwd.net/a1111/e11/test/example/file.flv`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to verify that it's working using rtmpdump found here:

https://github.com/mstorsjo/rtmpdump

Usage:

`rtmpdump -r "rtmp://example.fcod.llnwd.net/a1111/e11/test/example/file.flv" -o test.flv`

Answer (score 4):

You might be able to open up a "network location" via [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) player.

Comment: The version of VLC on my system doesn't seem to support RTMP however this solution *should* probably work otherwise. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There's a test player built for CRTMPD (But it'll work for any RTMP server)

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2918563/flvplayback.swf (Link broken)

Answer (score 2):

This will definitely work:
[http://www.vlc.eu.pn/](https://web.archive.org/web/20170913131937/http://www.vlc.eu.pn/) (Original link broken, archived page linked)

Just go to the link above and test your rtmp url, easy and fast!

Answer (score 1):

Since rtmpdump is not in the repos for some linuxes (centos), here is an option that uses a much more common tool (curl):

```
if [[ `curl --connect-timeout 1 --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail rtmp://cp67126.edgefcs.net/ondemand/mp4:mediapm/ovp/content/test/video/spacealonehd_sounas_640_300.mp4 2>&1` ]]
then
  echo "failing!"
else
  echo "working!"
fi
```

NOTE: This can have false positives (Says a stream is working when it's not) but it works well enough for my needs.